# Grails 3.0.1 - Folders missing?

Tags: grails, grails-3.0

I downloaded Grails 2.4.4 and created a test project (using NetBeans) and it was successful.

I downloaded Grails 3.0.1 and created a test project (using NetBeans) NetBeans says project created successfully but it did not load the project in to project explorer.

I compared Groovy folders of 2.4.4 and 3.0.1 and noticed that few folders are missing in the installation.

I confirmed that I downloaded the correct package.

These are the folders/files missing in Grails 3.0.1

**folders**
conf, 
doc, 
plugins, 
script

**files**
build.properties, 
readme

Comment: Grails 3.0 has a different structure than 2.x and below. Some of the files have been removed, and some of the folders have been removed too.

Comment: You may want to have a look at Graeme's Grails 3 Preview talk https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aro3_RZqgtU.  Only 6 minutes and should answer a lot of your questions.

Answer (score 2):

Grails 3.0 was a complete re-write of Grails and lots of things have changed. Not the least of which is the folder and file structure. Since Grails 3.0 is based on Spring Boot and Gradle a lot of what was very Grails specific has been removed and replaced with both of these.

This [blog entry](http://www.mscharhag.com/2015/04/whats-new-in-grails-3.html) gives a good amount of detail on what has changed in Grails 3.0. It even talks about directory/file structures.

Comment: Thanks Joshua !    
I just started with a project which was developed using Grails 2.0.1 and want implement new enhancements. Looks like it is better to upgrade to Grails 2.5 and leave 3.0.1 as a future upgrade ? Otherwise wouldn't it add lots of effort if I try to use 3.0.1 ?

Comment: It depends on how familiar you are with Grails. If you are just getting started I would stay with 2.5 since there are more resources to learn from. Otherwise, I would start any new projects with 3.0.1 and be aware that I'm using the latest and greatest (e.g. I might have to use workarounds or contribute patches) version of Grails.

Comment: So I would go for 2.5 and consider 3.0.1 for future upgrade.